# will async Rest API call with threads affect performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

So one of my colleagues was saying to me -

> "Why would somebody want to call async RestAPIs with thread, Its not beneficial and in return it will create a separate thread for every request."

My scenario is-

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<ProductLookupDto>> GetProductsByValueOfTheDay()
{
    string url = "http://domain.com?param=10120&isBasic=true"
    var result = Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductLookupDto>(SerializedResults.GET(url)));
    return new ApiResponse<ProductLookupDto>()
    {
        Data = await result,
        Message = "success"
    };
}
```

So here I am using async with threading. I know it will create a separate thread for request. Which is my concern about the performance.

I want to know if some of my methods are called together and if reponse is async as I am doing now. Will the thread affect to performance?
keeping in mind where - **response from rest call is too large.**

Comment: Threading and performance are two orthogonal concepts. Threads don't make your program faster. They just allows you to make some things in parallel, if this is possible at the moment.

Comment: This will create a separate *task* for each request - that will use the thread pool. There's reasonably-little overhead for creating a task. That said, you should read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx You should ideally be looking to use an async call for the `SerializedResuts.Get(...)` part.

Comment: It's also very unclear what you mean by "response from rest call is too large".

Comment: @JonSkeet, The end result that I get from rest API is large I meant.

Comment: How large is large, and what is it "too" large for? Basically if you want us to bear that in mind when we respond, you'll need to give more information.

Comment: Also, don't try to learn hundreds or thousands of prescriptive performance "rules". Write clear, readable code that gets that task done, and at the same time, set performance *goals* for the overall system. Then *measure* the performance. If it meets the goals, great, move on to the next job. If not, find out *where* your performance issue is and start assessing alternatives. Don't just try to learn "always do X" or "never do Y", since there are rarely any such absolutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend actually is not really knowing what he talks about - a Task will NOT create a separate thread for every request. Rather the task scheduler will determine threads - and the standard uses the thread pool. Which means that threads are pre allocated and reused, especially if you schedule a LOT of tasks. Also threads are released while the request runs due to completion ports. Your colleague shows a serious lack of basics here.

Comment: "Also threads are released while the request runs due to completion ports." Not here - there's a *synchronous* call fetching the response, so that will block whatever thread makes that call, until it completes. That's the key problem here - in order to efficiently avoid blocking threads, the OP really needs the web request to be made asynchronously.

Comment: @TomTom, Thanks to you and Jon Skeet. As I've understood I am doing it wrong way. Where it pretends to be async but not really. It will just create a background thread and reuse it over.

My concern is not to block UI thread though.

can you help me modifying it to be async?

Comment: Or: you actually use the ASYNC methods. I do a lot of rest processing and believe me, there actually IS an async API to make a rest request purely async.

Comment: @TomTom, So my method won't run asynchronously? as in [this](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/) example they say using `Task.Run` is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, you do not call an async method to start with, so you get no gain. Task.Run is not necessail a bad idea - if you need to do parallel processing, you need threads. Async /await is more for thread recycling, but for that you must use a proper async API. Which you do not. They coexist. I use both in a trading platform.

Comment: Maybe I'm giving the colleague too much credit but I don't think (s)he's _that_ far off. Wrapping a blocking I/O call in `Task.Run` rose a red flag, as it should have. No, you're not _creating_ a new thread every time, but you are faking asynchrony by moving a blocking call to a background thread, which is of little benefit in _most_ cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think your colleague is right to be concerned with that code, and you are right to say "it pretends to be async but not really". And Jon Skeet is right to point out that the real problem here lies with `SerializedResults.GET`. Whatever the implentation of that is exactly, it's clearly a blocking call, otherwise it would return a `Task<string>` (that can be `await`ed) instead of a string. Wrapping a synchronous call in `Task.Run` and calling it asynchronous is a common mistake. You haven't eliminated blocking at all, you've simply moved the blocking call to a different thread.

So to make this asynchronous, `SerializedResults.GET` needs to go. It should be replaced by a call that uses a truly asynchronous library like [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx). Since this is a JSON API (and I'm a little bit biased), I'll show you an example using my [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) library, which is basically a wrapper around HttpClient and Json.NET that provides some convenience methods to cut down on the noise a bit:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<ProductLookupDto>> GetProductsByValueOfTheDay()
{
    string url = "http://domain.com?param=10120&isBasic=true";
    var result = await url.GetJsonAsync<ProductLookupDto>();
    return new ApiResponse<ProductLookupDto>()
    {
        Data = result,
        Message = "success"
    };
}
```

Comment: `...but you are faking asynchrony by moving a blocking call to a background thread, which is of little benefit in most cases!`
How is this beneficial?

Comment: If this code is from a Windows app, moving the blocking call to a background thread keeps the UI thread responsive. But "real" asynchrony achieves the same without consuming an extra thread. That is far preferable.